# Determine whether the image is taken from the device's camera besides model and manufacturer information

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-image

I would like to know, is there any other way to determine whether the image that is stored in the device is taken from the device's camera. I am able to obtain some of the information through ExifInterface such as model and manufacturer, but is there any way to determine that it is from that particular device, rather than just the model and manufacturer?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hopefully not. Having photos automatically tagged with something individually identifiable would be a privacy violation.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh right, that's true. oh well, I guess I have to stick to model and manufacturer then. thanks.

Comment: … but if you want to track pictures captured by _your_ app, you can add an additional EXIF flag or even a visible or [hidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) watermark.